# Are the Old Testament prohibitions on incest applicable to Christians?

Tags: old-testament, mosaic-law, morality, incest

The Old Testament forbids incest. Does this aspect of the Mosaic law apply to Christians?

Comment: Leviticus 18:16 is observed in the Gospel of [Mark 6:17-18], alluding to Christian observance all the Laws in Leviticus 18 regarding incest.

Answer (score 2):

Are the Old Testament prohibitions on incest applicable to Christians? - Yes.

**Leviticus 18:16 is observed in the Gospel of [Mark 6:17-18], alluding to Christian observance all the Laws in Leviticus 18 regarding incest.**

---

**Leviticus 18:16 in regards to Mark 6:17-18** :

Mark 6:17-18 [KJV]

> 17 For Herod himself had sent forth and laid hold upon John, and bound him in prison for Herodias' sake, his brother Philip's wife: for he had married her.

18 For John had said unto Herod, It is not lawful for thee to have thy brother's wife.

- Leviticus 18:16 [MT]

  > You shall not uncover the nakedness of your brother's wife. It is your brother's nakedness. (עֶרְוַ֥ת אֵֽשֶׁת־אָחִ֖יךָ לֹ֣א תְגַלֵּ֑ה עֶרְוַ֥ת אָחִ֖יךָ הִֽוא)

Comment: How do you know that John was referring to Levitical law, and not Roman law?

Comment: This only proves Herod was ignoring a Jewish law   It says nothing about Christianity

Comment: This doesn't answer the question in the slightest. You're assuming Mark is referring to Leviticus, and you're further assuming this means the entirety of Leviticus is to be followed. Do you have any evidence to back these assumptions up?

Answer (score 0):

The laws of all decent countries forbid incest. So, yes, The Law (all law) about incest applies to all citizens, Christians included.

Comment: You've moved the goalposts. Firstly, you're claiming that "decent" countries forbid incest. But your standard for what is decent or not should be the Bible. So in order to show a country is decent, you need to show it follows the Bible. Secondly, I'm not asking whether or not Christians need to follow the law of the land, I already know this. I'm asking whether Christianity prohibits incest. At least try to answer the actual question asked...

Answer (score -1):

Yes it does. Most mosaic laws apply unless stated otherwise in the New Testament. But the NT consistently talks about sexual immorality, which would include incest and other things.

Comment: Please provide evidence. Are you saying the laws about not wearing mixed fabrics are applicable today?